# Would it be haraam if I killed a spider on night of Qadr (Laylat al-Qadr)?

Tags: halal-haram, laylat-al-qadr

Would it be haraam if I killed a spider on the night of Qadr?
I have no idea about this but i become very scared when i see it so killed it ...Please tell me for this reason my dua and other things i do will be lose or not please help me

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is not permitted to kill any life that Allah has made scared, whether it is on the night of Qadr or not.

Say: "Come I will rehearse what Allah hath (really) prohibited you from": join not anything with Him; Be good to your parents: kill not your children on a plea of want;― provide sustenance for you and for them;― come not nigh to shameful deeds, whether open or secret; **take not life, which Allah hath made sacred, except by way of justice and law**: thus doth He command you, that ye may learn wisdom. (6:151)

Answer (score -2):

There is no special prohibition in night of qadr.
If you're expecting a fear from a spider, [no problem in killing it](https://www.assimalhakeem.net/2017/05/08/sir-what-is-the-ruling-of-killing-insects-like-wherever-i-see-spider-or-cockroaches-i-kill-them-pardon-me-if-my-question-is-stupid/)

Comment: Thanks for replying ....